# How to set a custom R installation for using rpy2 in Jupyter?

Tags: r, kernel, jupyter, conda, rpy2

I have a conda environment which I made available as a kernel to my Jupyter instance by running:
`python -m ipykernel install --user --name my-env-name --display-name "Python (my-env-name)"`

With this environment I wanted to use R in Jupyter taking advantage of `rpy2`'s `%load_ext rpy2.ipython` command to enable the `%%R` magic. However, `rpy2` is employing my global R and not the one installed in my conda environment. I checked my R home via:

```
%%R
R.home()
```

(I can also check the situation with `%run -m rpy2.situation` in Jupyter notebook ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46256945/installing-an-r-library-to-work-with-r-magic-in-an-anaconda-jupyter-notebook)), however this seems to be broken in `rpy2` somewhere between versions `3.1.0` and `3.2.1` ... at least for me it was throwing `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'rpy2' referenced before assignment` in `3.1.0` and it was working for `3.2.1`).

How can I make my Jupyter notebook load the R installation from my conda environment?

Comment: `%run -m rpy2.situation` appears to be working with the current rpy2 release (3.2.6). If there was a bug, it was fixed and update to the latest release would be recommended.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Just tried it on `3.2.1` which also works. I adjusted the question accordingly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two approaches to solve this, a local (for individual Jupyter notebooks) and a global one (for the kernel itself). Both are related to setting the `R_HOME` environment variable.

**Local** ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60114970/cannot-import-rpy2-in-jupyter-notebook-fail-to-call-r-in-python)):
Before calling `%load_ext rpy2.ipython` in your Jupyter notebook, run:

```
import os
os.environ['R_HOME'] = '/home/your/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/R' #path to your R installation
```

**Global**:
Find your kernel directory via: `jupyter kernelspec list` and edit the file `kernel.json`. Update the JSON by adding:
`"env": {"R_HOME":"/home/your/anaconda3/envs/my-env-name/lib/R"}`, then restart your kernel (you might have to restart Jupyter as well).

## Update (messed up `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`)

Recently, I tried running `rpy2` in jupyter again after setting up a new environment using `conda`:

```
conda config --add channels conda-forge
conda config --set channel_priority strict
conda create -n myenv python=3.7
conda activate myenv
conda install r-essentials pandas rpy2
```

And this time I ran into the following issue when trying to either `%load_ext rpy2.ipython` (Jupyter) or simply `import rpy2.robjects` (any script):

```
>>> import rpy2.robjects                                            
Warning message:                                                    
package ‘methods’ was built under R version 3.6.3     
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘stats’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/home/your/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/R/library/stats/libs/stats.so':                  
  /home/your/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/R/library/stats/libs/stats.so: undefined symbol: MARK_NOT_MUTABLE
During startup - Warning messages:                                                                                          
1: package ‘datasets’ was built under R version 3.6.3      
2: package ‘utils’ was built under R version 3.6.3                                                                     
3: package ‘grDevices’ was built under R version 3.6.3  
4: package ‘graphics’ was built under R version 3.6.3                                                                       
5: package ‘stats’ was built under R version 3.6.3          
6: package ‘stats’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found                                                       
R[write to console]: Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tools’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/home/your/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/R/library/tools/libs/tools.so':
  /home/your/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/R/library/tools/libs/tools.so: undefined symbol: R_NewPreciousMSet

R[write to console]: Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) :
  unable to load shared object '/home/your/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/R/library/tools/libs/tools.so':
  /home/your/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/R/library/tools/libs/tools.so: undefined symbol: R_NewPreciousMSet

R[write to console]: In addition:                                      
R[write to console]: Warning message:                        

R[write to console]: package ‘tools’ was built under R version 3.6.3

Traceback (most recent call last):                          
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>                    
  File "/home/your/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    import rpy2.robjects.functions                                           
  File "/home/your/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/functions.py", line 12, in <module>
    from rpy2.robjects import help                                   
  File "/home/your/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/help.py", line 43, in <module>
    tools_ns = _get_namespace(StrSexpVector(('tools',)))          
  File "/home/your/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface_lib/conversion.py", line 44, in _
    cdata = function(*args, **kwargs)                                     
  File "/home/your/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface.py", line 621, in __call__
    raise embedded.RRuntimeError(_rinterface._geterrmessage())                            
rpy2.rinterface_lib.embedded.RRuntimeError: Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) :
  unable to load shared object '/home/your/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/R/library/tools/libs/tools.so':
  /home/your/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/R/library/tools/libs/tools.so: undefined symbol: R_NewPreciousMSet
```

The issue seemed to have been a screwed up R "situation" (check via `%run -m rpy2.situation` in Jupyter or simply `python -m rpy2.situation` on the command line), which had `R's additions to LD_LIBRARY_PATH:` pointing to and old, globally installed R version.

I had to manually unset the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to solve this issue. This path can be set / unset analogously to `R_HOME`.

PS: I found `R_HOME` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` set in my `.bashrc` to custom (from source) R installation. Which confused the Jupyter kernel obviously. Not smart ;)

PPS: `rpy2.situation` still tells me that there is a `Warning: The environment variable R_HOME differs from the default R in the PATH.`:

```
Looking for R's HOME:
    Environment variable R_HOME: /home/your/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/R
    Calling `R RHOME`: /home/your/anaconda3/envs/jupyter-env/lib/R
    Environment variable R_LIBS_USER: None
    Warning: The environment variable R_HOME differs from the default R in the PATH.
```

Which worries me that `R` actually defaults to the R installed for the Jupyter installation. So if anybody has comments about this, I would be grateful.

Comment: This solution also works in a regular script on python. After installing _rpy2_ I got an error related to the R_Path: `ValueError: r_home is None. Try python -m rpy2.situation` Before I import _rpy2_ I set the "R_HOME" as @martin-becker explain and it solves the probem.

Comment: @MartinBecker I tried with `os.environ['R_HOME'] = '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources'` before to run `%load_ext rpy2.ipython`, but it returns me a lot of errors: last line is LookupError: 'show' not found